# Set project version to dependency's latest version

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have this POM.xml project file:

```
<project>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>someartifact</artifactId>
<version>2.0.5</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany></groupId>
        <artifactId>anotherartifact</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version> <!-- Corresponds to 2.0.5 -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

As you can see, the `anotherartifact` dependency version is set to `LATEST`, which corresponds to `2.0.5`. Plus, my current project, `someartifact`, also has a version of `2.0.5`. How can I make the `someartifact` version to always be set to the same version as the dependency's version, automatically?

Comment: You have to create a  parent module (pom project) for both of your artifacts. See [Maven Inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

You would do the reverse. Set the dependency version to use `${project.version}`.